Storage of customer data to database during Supabse authentication process
in my mobile application, 2 different types of users are auth.

client
doctor.

If type=client the data to the Client database must be stored. If type=doctor the data to the Doctor database must be saved. what I have a problem is in query, that is, the type must be checked and saved to the desired database.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/SjJvz.jpg)
